# Outputting Highest/Average Score From List Of 3 (Value) For Each Student (Key) In A Dictionary Sorted From Highest To Lowest?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating three ways that the scores of students in a class (which are stored in a dictionary called `scores`) can be viewed.

The first method is to view the highest score of each student (which is taken from each student's list (their value), which consists of between 1 and 3 scores), sorted in alphabetical order by the student's name (their entry's key). This is done using the following code:

```
for name, highScore in [(student,max(scores[student])) for student in sorted(scores.keys())]:
    print(name, highScore)
```

The output of this:

```
David Sherwitz 9
Michael Bobby 1
Tyrone Malone 6
```

The second method is to view the highest score of each student, sorted from highest to lowest. The code I created for this:

```
sortB = []
for name, highScore in [(student, max(scores[student])) for student in scores.keys()]:
    sortB += name, highScore
print(sortB)
```

The output of this:

```
['David Sherwitz', 9, 'Michael Bobby', 1, 'Tyrone Malone', 6]
```

I would like this output to look similar to the output of the first method, but it doesn't? It's not also not sorted from highest to lowest. How can I make it do that?

The third method is to view the average score of each student, sorted from highest to lowest. I haven't created the code for this yet, but I think it would be possible to modify the code for the second method so that it gets the average score instead, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to run `.sort` on the 2nd column, which can be defined by `key=lambda x: x[1]`:

```
sortB = [(n, max(s)) for n,s in scores.items()]
sortB.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for name, highScore in sortB:
    print(name, highScore)
```

Similarly, to sort by average, just replace `max` with the average function:

```
sortC = [(n, float(sum(s))/len(s)) for n,s in scores.items()]
sortC.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for name, avgScore in sortC:
    print(name, avgScore)
```

Here's sorting with first method and using similar coding style:

```
sortA = [(n,max(s)) for n,s in scores.items()]
sortA.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
for name, highScore in sortA:
    print(name, highScore)
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the first sorting method (A) similar to B and C in terms of style, as I've done it without creating a list called `sortA`?

Comment: np. just realized it could be coded more succinctly with `scores.items()`. see updated answer for all 3 methods